# Error compiling Marlin with VSCode and PlatformIO

Tags: visual-studio-code, platformio

I have the following error coming from VScode and I do not know what to do with it.

```
Building in release mode
RuntimeError: deque mutated during iteration:
  File "C:\Users\dobrevi\.platformio\penv\lib\site-packages\platformio\builder\main.py", line 181:
    env.SConscript(env.GetExtraScripts("post"), exports="env")
  File "C:\Users\dobrevi\.platformio\packages\tool-scons\scons-local-4.5.2\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 598:
    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)
  File "C:\Users\dobrevi\.platformio\packages\tool-scons\scons-local-4.5.2\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 285:
    exec(compile(scriptdata, scriptname, 'exec'), call_stack[-1].globals)
  File "C:\Users\dobrevi\Documents\3D\SovolSV06\Firmware\hillsoftware\buildroot\share\PlatformIO\scripts\custom_board.py", line 14:
    marlin.relocate_firmware(address)
  File "C:\Users\dobrevi\Documents\3D\SovolSV06\Firmware\hillsoftware\buildroot\share\PlatformIO\scripts\marlin.py", line 26:
    replace_define("VECT_TAB_ADDR", address)
    for define in env['CPPDEFINES']:
================================================================== [FAILED] Took 23.78 seconds ================================================================== 

Environment               Status    Duration
------------------------  --------  ------------
GD32F103RET6_sovol_maple  FAILED    00:00:23.779
```

Previously I was able to compile it and haven't used VSCode since.

I would appreciate any guidance.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to copy the marlin.py file form its original source to my repo/folder
https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/c2decc3e2e30c7cb0f517b7e40d8138a8c1d4a81/buildroot/share/PlatformIO/scripts/marlin.py

This helped me better understand the issue: https://community.platformio.org/t/trying-to-compile-marlin-2-1-2-for-ender-3-skr-mini-v2-0-board/33769/10